# Show the tooltip when mouse over at the object unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gkturnbasedmatch

i wanted to show the tooltip like this when the mouse over at the object, here is the example image:

[image]

and

[image]

i already tried this below code, but the message on the debug.log didn't showed up when i am hovering my mouse to the object, the object i give the name same like this:

```
void Update() 
{

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Yify")
    {

        Debug.Log("Yify");

    }

}
```

And here is my object (i use List to multiple the objects and each object i gave the name), (The object's name "Yify" is on the right side, dark green color):

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
void Update(){
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit ;
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100.0) && hit.collider.gameObject.name=="Yify") {
          Debug.Log("Yify");
        }
    }
```

Comment: when the mouse is over the object (hovering the object), it will display or show the button on top of the hovering object. (e.g: like the second image that i mention in the question)